# Запуск python сервера с указанием пути другого компьютера

Tags: python, сервер, http

Можно ли запустить сервер на Python на первом компьютере, а папку с ресурсами взять из локальной сети(второй компьютер). Как это сделать?

Comment: вопрос неясен. Что конкретно вы имеете ввиду? Вы хотите запустить `python` на удалённой машине?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найдено решение: в сети запустить файл сервера, скрипт сам пропишет нужный путь